# Cant get id from main query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I created a query with a subquery in it and tried to make it into eloquent, my problem is the add select part doesnt work, i always get 0 from the sum of my subquery

```
SELECT
    cr.code,
    cr.date,
    u.name,
(SELECT
    SUM( items.amount ) 
FROM
    payments
    LEFT JOIN items ON payments.item_id = items.id 
WHERE
    cashout_id IS NULL 
    AND items.seller_id = cr.seller_id 
    ) AS amount,
    cr.status 
FROM
    cashout_requests cr
    LEFT JOIN users u ON cr.id = u.id
    LEFT JOIN cashout_statuses cs ON cr.`status` = cs.id
```

and i make a eloquent query for it but i cant get the sum of amount

```
$items = cashoutRequest::select('cashout_requests.code', 'cashout_requests.date', 'users.name', 'cashout_statuses.status')
            ->addSelect(
                [
                    'amount' =>
                        payment::select('items.amount')
                        ->leftJoin('items','payments.item_id','=','items.id')
                        ->whereNull('cashout_id')
                        ->where('items.seller_id','=','cashout_requests.seller_id')
                        ->sum('items.amount')
                ]
            )
            ->leftJoin('users','cashout_requests.id','=','users.id')
            ->leftJoin('cashout_statuses','cashout_requests.status','=','cashout_statuses.id')
            ->get();
```

`->where('items.seller_id','=','cashout_requests.seller_id')`

this condition doesnt work  cant get the

Answer (score 0):

Your `->addSelect()` should be after your `->leftJoin()`'s. Otherwise the data you are trying to add in the `addSelect` is not available.

Comment: i got this error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: select `cashout_requests`.`code`, `cashout_requests`.`date`, `users`.`name`, `cashout_statuses`.`status`, `0` from `cashout_requests` left join `users` on `cashout_requests`.`id` = `users`.`id` left join `cashout_statuses` on `cashout_requests`.`status` = `cashout_statuses`.`id`)